# Nginx variable for physical server name

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to setup response headers on my separate webservers that outputs the physical name of the machine that nginx is running on, so that I can tell which servers are serving the responses to our web clients.

Is there a variable that exists to do this already? Or do I just have to hardcode it per-server :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're after the [$hostname](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_hostname) common variable.  Common variables are listed in the [variable index](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html).

The [nginx access log documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html) only shows variables that are specific to the access log:

> The log format can contain common variables, and variables that exist
>   only at the time of a log write.

Comment: I'll be damned, I don't know how I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess  you're looking for [`$hostname`](http://nginx.org/r/$hostname) variable.

Answer (score -1):

At first I thought the answer was to use the ENV variable and pull out the hostname from there https://docs.apitools.com/blog/2014/07/02/using-environment-variables-in-nginx-conf.html. But I couldn't get it to work for some reason.

However, this works like a charm:

`perl_set $server_int 'sub { use Sys::Hostname; return hostname; }';`

And example usage:

`add_header 'Server-Int' "$server_int";`

Just have to make sure your nginx is compiled with `--with-http_perl_module` - just run `nginx -V` to make sure. And that you have Sys::Hostname installed.

**Warning**: I at first used `hostname` to return the hostname in the Perl script, but while that did return the name, it for some reason aborted the rest of the output. I don't know if it's a bug with perl_set but you've been warned - using backticks in perl_set may be deadly.